# Manipulate Slider to take its values from primes

Tags: manipulate, prime-numbers, slider

How do I make the slider values in Manipulate be values that are prime numbers?
Many thanks for any assistance.

Firstly, many thanks for all your considered and rapid responses. It really is very much appreciated. Here is my Mathematica 'code' to produce some tables that demonstrate a small Lemma about residue classes. In the last section I am seeking that the p-input variable only selects primes.
`Manipulate[{MatrixForm[Table[x + y p^(r - 1 - t), {x, 0, p^t - 1}, {y, 0, p - 1}]], MatrixForm[Table[Mod[x + y p^(r - 1 - t), p^t], {x, 0, p^t - 1}, {y, 0, p - 1}]], Transpose[Table[Sort[Table[Mod[x + y p^(r - 1 - t), p^t], {x, 0, p^t - 1}, {y, 0, p - 1}][[All, i]]], {i, 1, p}]] // MatrixForm},
{p, 2, 100, 1}, {r, 1, 10, 1}, {t, 0, r - 1, 1}]`

Just as a side-bar, sorting the individual matrix columns was difficult for me with no easy global sort function (like Excel) readily available. Cheers.

Comment: Firstly, many thanks for all your considered and rapid responses. It really is very much appreciated. Here is my Mathematica 'code' to produce some tables that demonstrate a small Lemma about residue classes. In the last section I am seeking that the p-input variable only selects primes.

Comment: If you have version 10+ make use of `TrackingFunction`, and replace controlling of `p` with `{p, 2, 100, 1, Appearance->"Labeled", TrackingFunction -> (If[PrimeQ[#], p=#]&)}`.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the example from [`TrackingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html):

```
Manipulate[x, {{x, 2}, 0, 100, 1, TrackingFunction -> (If[PrimeQ[#], x = #] &)}]
```

Comment: You can also interconnect in both directions: `Manipulate[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1, 
  TrackingFunction -> (x = #; y = (1 - #); &)}, {y, 0, 1, 
  TrackingFunction -> (y = #; x = (1 - #); &)}]`

Comment: Combined with the [approach by BoLe](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121815/18476): `Manipulate[p,
 {{n, 1}, 1, 100, 1, Slider, 
  TrackingFunction :> (n = #; p = Prime[n]; &), 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{p, Prime[n]}, None}]`

Comment: @Karsten7. Yep. If I were to do it BoLe's way, I would use `With`: `Manipulate[With[{p = Prime[n]}, p], {n, 1, 10, 1}]`. But the solution in the docs has a certain cuteness in how the slider jumps from a prime position to the next, if one finds the gaps between primes interesting.  And if you open the slider (or set it to be `"Labeled"`), it displays the prime number, instead the prime's ordinal position, the reasons for wanting it to be one way or the other depending on the application.

Answer (score 7):

Keep slider linear and have another variable.

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{p = Prime[n]}, p],
 {n, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Or, specify a setter bar but then force slider.

```
With[{k = 10},
 Manipulate[n,
  {n, Prime /@ Range[k], ControlType -> Slider}]]
```

Or, make a custom interactive structure without `Manipulate`.

```
With[{k = 10},
 DynamicModule[{x},
  Column[{
    Slider[Dynamic[x], {Prime /@ Range[k]}],
    Dynamic[(a + b)^x]}]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending in what you actually want with the `Manipulate`, `DynamicModule[]` is not really required:

```
data = Table[i^2 - i, {i, 30}];
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[data/Prime[a], PlotLabel -> {"i^2-i/", Prime[a]}], {a, 1, 30, 1}]
```